# Wrong Number or type of argument <Proc_Name> and Last record got displayed twice - PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AVG_MARK
(
    CROLL_NUM OUT TEST_TBL.ROLL_NUM%type,
    CNAME OUT TEST_TBL.NAME%type,
    CAVG_SALARY OUT TEST_TBL.SALARY%type
    CRANK OUT INTEGER
)
AS 
CURSOR C1 IS 
    SELECT ROLL_NUM, NAME, SALARY, RANK() OVER ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS RNK
    FROM TEST_TBL;
BEGIN
OPEN C1;
    LOOP
        FETCH C1 INTO CROLL_NUM , CNAME , CAVG_SALARY , CRANK;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CROLL_NUM  ||','|| CNAME ||','|| CAVG_SALARY ||','|| CRANK);
        EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND
    END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

Inside select query returns 5 records

1. I am able to Compile above proc but while executing it says
   "Wrong number or type of arguments in call to AVG_MARK"
2. And while opening the Proc and executing it will connect to database and displays the records but last record gets repeated twice.

Please advice on this issue

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are passing the values to the procedure. I created a sample table like yours with some records, and it works for me.Only thing I changed in the procedure was to fix some syntax errors and put the `EXIT WHEN` immediately after `FETCH`. That is the reason why you were seeing last record repeated.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE avg_mark (croll_num   OUT test_tbl.roll_num%TYPE, 
                                      cname       OUT test_tbl.name%TYPE, 
                                      cavg_salary OUT test_tbl.salary%TYPE, 
                                      crank       OUT INTEGER) 
AS 
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT roll_num, 
           name, 
           salary, 
           RANK() 
             over ( 
               ORDER BY salary DESC) AS RNK 
    FROM   test_tbl; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN c1; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c1 INTO croll_num, cname, cavg_salary, crank; 

        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND; 

        dbms_output.put_line(croll_num 
                             ||',' 
                             || cname 
                             ||',' 
                             || cavg_salary 
                             ||',' 
                             || crank); 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c1; 
END; 

/
```

Here's the invocation.

```
DECLARE 
    v_croll_num   test_tbl.roll_num%TYPE; 
    v_cname       test_tbl.name%TYPE; 
    v_cavg_salary test_tbl.salary%TYPE; 
    v_crank       INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
    avg_mark(v_croll_num, v_cname, v_cavg_salary, v_crank); 
END; 

/
```

**O/p**

```
1,Kaushik,1000000000,1
2,Rhodes,1000,2
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10929d4277622b372d8f79986b83b0f0)

Comment: I couldn't see any syntax error which you mentioned.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Just these 2 silly ones, that's all  `RANK() OVER ORDER BY SALARY DESC)`  parentheses missing. `EXIT WHEN ` . semicolon missing.

Comment: Thank you so much .. It works when I place EXIT statement before DBMS_OUTPUT